# Formatting of a sentence with text box on one line

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have the following Bootstrap row on my page:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    I, <input type="text" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control input-lg" />,
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    hereby acknowledge that I understand my responsibility as an:
  </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I run the code, I see that the text box becomes lower than "I,".

I tried to limit the size of the text box and also tried to put "I," in another col, but then the text box becomes very far apart from "I,". This is the code that I tried:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    I,
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" size="10" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control input-lg" />,
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    hereby acknowledge that I understand my responsibility as an:
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to keep "I,  box and then "hereby acknowledge that I understand my responsibility" on one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [inline form](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#inline-forms) option doesn't help here. Neither do columns, which are rarely going to space things properly.

We instead need to force inline display and auto width on the input, both of which are configured differently by default on mobile.

I left it all in a column as I assume you'll need this for your overall layout. It's not necessary that the sentence be in *any* container, though.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mt-3">
      I, <input class="form-control d-inline w-auto input-lg" type="text" asp-for="FullName" />, hereby acknowledge that I understand my responsibility as an:
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is already an inline element. Why not simply put it all in the same column without breaking the sentence into weird columns?

You don't need a special class for full-width elements.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    I,
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" size="10" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control input-lg" />,
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    hereby acknowledge that I understand my responsibility as an:
  </div>

  <div>
    I, <input type="text" size="10" asp-for="FullName" class="form-control input-lg" />, hereby acknowledge that I understand my responsibility as an:
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: prkos: its working in your case because you didn't put bootstrap in your code. If you put bootstrap, the line will split into three rows. It seems class "Form -control" is doing that. I am not sure how to get around with this.

Comment: You didn't include the code that is affecting your case, so how can anyone help? Bootstrap columns are set to display one next to another :p The .form-control class is probably the one having display: block on it, making it go into its own "row". You need to override the CSS for that input field with `display: inline; width: auto;` to get the desired outcome.